# entry submission error logged in as client user - "You are not authorized to perform this action"

Tags: members, error, entry, permissions

Anyone seen this issue?

I'm logged in as the client who is under the member's group (I believe I have set all the required permissions, can't see anything obvious that would restrict this).

When I try and re-submit an entry in the client's account where the Author is the Super Admin, I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXwYC.jpg

Comment: I am having the same issue since the update to 2.6.1. Pretty sure its a bug. My suggestion would be to update to the latest. I haven't done so, but I plan to very soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this permission for their member group: *Can change the author name when posting channel entries*. (Under Members → Member Groups → Edit Member Group.)

[image: Member Group Preferences]

Comment: I'm having this same issue, why would "Can change the author name when posting channel entries" have any bearing on whether a certain member group can edit an entry posted originally by a super admin?  I gave the member group permission to edit another members entries...Seems like this is a bug as I've never had this issue before...